# .NET Core App running inside an IFRAME on a WordPress page can't read shared cookies, but if run outside the IFRAME the app can

Tags: wordpress, cookies, iframe, https

I've got an .NET Core application running inside an IFRAME on a WordPress site.

- Wordpress site: http://staging.mysite.com
- .NET Core app in IFRAME:
  https://app.mysite.com

The .NET Core app gets a cookie set by WordPress and uses it, it uses this method:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("LoggedUserToken", out var userToken);
```

The cookie appears as follows in Chrome:

```
Name: LoggedUserToken
Value: cB/7TkfmgY+Wiz+yoxYZpfd5cHy4Qenx
Domain: .mysite.com
Path: /
Expires: 2022-01-21T11:04:37.539Z
HttpOnly: (blank)
Secure: (blank)
Samesite: (blank)
SameParty: (blank)
Priority: (medium)
```

When I load the WordPress page with the IFRAME, the IFRAME fails to find the cookie, it is blank.

If I load the IFRAME directly in the browser (app.mysite.com) it finds the shared domain cookie and uses the value correctly.

The thing is the same system works fine on three other WordPress sites, though they are a different flavour (they are Bitnami multistack, and this problem one is Trellis/Sage/Bedrock single site).

So I'm thinking this cold be WordPress somehow messing up the IFRAME? Or not sending the cookies somehow?

Why would this work in an IFRAME on one WP site, but not another? Why would it work outside the IFRAME but not in it?

Is this because the staging site is http and the web app is https? Is there an issue with an IFRAME running inside an http site that means it can't load shared cookies, but when you run it in the browser outside the iframe is can read the exact same cookies?

Confused.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both the WordPress site and the app in the IFRAME needed to be on https, if the WP site is on http then the https IFRAME can't access the shamed domain cookies. As soon as I made the wp site https it all worked fine.